# Zend select() count

Tags: zend-framework, count

I have a problem, I need to perform a COUNT query before executing the original query, for the needs of pagination, so I will know what's the predicted number of records I will receive from original query.

My original query looks like that:

```
  $select = $this->getAdapter()->select()
            ->from(array('u' => 'user'), array('id', 'name', 'addedDate' => 'MAX(t.added_date)'))
            ->joinLeft(array('t' => 'transaction'), 'u.id = t.user_id', array('added_date'))
            ->group('u.id')
            ->order('COALESCE(MAX(t.added_date), "9999-00-00 00:00:00") ASC')
```

In count query I wont fetch the fields, i only need to know how many records will be returned by DB. any ideas?

I tried to put 'count'=>'COUNT(u.id)' in the from clause, but it's not counting all the records, but original number of fitting records from joined table for each record of main table,  so in the result under count key, I see that user.id 1 had for example 3 matches in table transaction

Comment: Why not just use [Zend_Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html) or [Zend\Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two Zend_Db_Select objects:

```
$select = $this->getAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('u' => 'user'), array('id', 'name', 'addedDate' => 'MAX(t.added_date)'))
        ->joinLeft(array('t' => 'transaction'), 'u.id = t.user_id', array('added_date'))
        ->group('u.id')
        ->order('COALESCE(MAX(t.added_date), "9999-00-00 00:00:00") ASC');

$countRowsSelect = $this->getAdapter()->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from(array('cnt' => $select), array('row_count' => 'COUNT(*)'));

$countRow = $countRows->query()->fetchAll();
echo 'There are ' . $countRow[0]['row_count'] . 'rows!';
```

It's equals to the SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS row_count FROM
( -- your query with GROUP BY here -- ) cnt
```

However, when you've got a complete Zend_Db_Select, just use the Zend_Paginator:

```
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
```

It's much easier.

Comment: thansk, I will check it, I know Zend_Paginator, but I'm just preparing  implementation basing on someones else code so I have to stick to the current interface which doesnt use Zend_Paginator

Comment: It works great, just the results are under $count_row[0]['row_count'], thank you, I will vote it up as soon as I will reach reputation > 15

Comment: Sure, I forgot I'm using fetchAll() instead of fetchRow(). I've edited my answer.